# Difference in the checksum SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

What is the difference between the 2 different statements below? Please explain the output.

```
 SELECT CHECKSUM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,30))
```

Result : 51136012

```
 DECLARE @AA NVARCHAR
SET @AA= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,30)
SELECT CHECKSUM(@AA)
```

Result: 38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default lengths are different.  In the first, it is something like 32.  But when you do:

```
 declare @aa nvarchar;
```

The default length is 1.  So, the second is only using the first character.

In SQL Server, *always* use lengths with the `varchar()` types:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), 30))

DECLARE @AA NVARCHAR(255);
SET @AA= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), 30);
SELECT CHECKSUM(@AA);
```